# Webpack: Import a file that has functions in the global namespace and have them available?

Tags: webpack, ecmascript-6

I am trying to import a file using webpack, I do my normal:

```
import "../../lib/SampleFunctions.js";
```

Inside this sample functions there are a number of functions created directly on the global namespace i.e.

```
function CreateItem()
{

};

function CreaturePack(inside)
{

};

// constructor
CreaturePack.prototype = Object.create(CreateItem.prototype);
```

but the problem is that CreatePack or CreateItem are not available in the global namespace.

I thought I could fix this using the expose plugin, maybe I am using it wrong.. but I did the following

```
      {test: /SampleFunctions\.js$/, loader: 'expose?CreaturePack'},
```

I now have a CreaturePack but it's an empty object, and what about CreateItem ?

How can I do this? I want to be able to use import ".....file" but have my objects created in the global scope. The SomeFunctions is a sample and the real file is extremely complex so I cannot refactor it to use ES6 modules.

Is there some other better loader that places everything inside the global namespace ?

I have some other files that use it and expects these functions on the global namespace.

Comment: Have you looked at [`expose-members-loader`](https://github.com/davidpelayo/expose-members-loader)?

Comment: I'm skeptical that you "cannot refactor it to use ES6 modules." If you want the functions in the global namespace, that means they have names, and if they have names you can put `export` before each one. Even if you have hundreds of functions that's not a lot of work. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the `expose-loader`, you need to use the [`exports-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#exports-loader).

Comment: *I have some other files that use it and expects these functions on the global namespace*. Sounds like the OP wants the functions to be global instead of refactoring those other files to use CommonJs

Comment: In this case, the [`script-loader`](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/#script-loader) might be of interest. The [shimming](https://webpack.js.org/guides/shimming/) guide of webpack describes various options and usecases to work with non-modules.

Answer (score 0):

@Martin : So, if I understand your requirement correctly, 
you wanted to have some Global Object in your Project [it may consist of Server_Name, Version, etc] and use it across your modules.

If so, you can import that Common Module in Webpack.config.js at the top, assign it to some local object and put it in **externals** object of Webpack.

```
var CommonModule = require('./config');

module.exports = {
........
   externals: {
       'appConfig': JSON.stringify(CommonModule)
   }
........
}
```

Then, you can directly import that across different modules GLobally.

```
import appConfig from 'appConfig';
```